# Regla de Extracción en Web Test en Visual Studio

Tags: test

Tengo un Web Test en Visual Studio que utiliza un regla de extracción de la respuesta de un JSON. Cuando ejecuto la prueba por si solo (sin incluir la regla) funciona correctamente pero cuando agrego la regla presenta el siguiente error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'WebAndLoadTestProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
>   Nombre de archivo: 'WebAndLoadTestProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>      en System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>      en System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
>      en System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
>      en Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTestRuleBase.get_Type()
>      en Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.ExtractionRuleReference.CreateInstance()
>      en Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestInstrumentedTransaction.ExecuteExtractionRuleReferences(ExtractionRuleReferenceCollection extractionRuleReferences, Boolean rulesAreCorrelationRules)
>
> AVS: El registro del enlace de ensamblado está desactivado.
>   Para habilitar el registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado, establezca el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) como 1.
>   Nota: existe una disminución del rendimiento asociada registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado.
>   Para desactivar esta característica, elimine el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

El código de la regla de extracción es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden ayudar se lo agradezco.

Comment: Agrega el código en lugar de una imagen, date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de la misma manera, mira los ingredientes de una buena pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

regularmente este inconveniente se da cuando la **dll** que quiere utilizar no se encuentra en el proyecto o en el lugar donde se realizará la instalación.

Si este es el inconveniente verifica que la **dll** a utilizar se encuentre en la carpeta Bin o si es correcta la instalación del **Framework** utilizada.

**Nota:** *limpia el proyecto y re-compila nuevamente.*